# Pattern matching for htaccess rewrite rules involving one folder to another

Tags: regex, .htaccess, pattern-matching

I need some quick help cleaning up the following rules for htaccess file, as the list is getting quite long.

This has occurred after a site move which makes author pages that previously came from `/browse/author/NAME-HERE` now sit at `/by/NAME-HERE`.

Surely there's a way to pattern match these or something?

```
Redirect /browse/author/some-person /by/some-person
Redirect /browse/author/another-person /by/another-person
Redirect /browse/author/some-other-person /by/some-other-person
Redirect /browse/author/yet-more /by/yet-more
Redirect /browse/author/ /
```

I'd like to keep the `/browse/author/` redirect to the root though, if possible...

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible with mod_rewrite.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?browse/author/(.*) /by/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```